# How to make static and dynamic exports compatible in Next.js

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next.js14

I'm using both static export and dynamic build for hosting one website. Most of the pages are from static export, hosted from s3, but I needed couple dynamic routes as well.

With Next 13 I set it all up as follows:

- custom .babelrc - (only preset)
- separate build steps for static and dynamic site

This doesn't seem to work with Next 14. I set `BUILD_ID`, but I still sometimes get chunks that have the same prefix but different hashes in the file name.

1. Is there any way to build static and dynamic site in one step? This would fix filename problem.
2. Is it possible to set it all up with SWC, without custom .babelrc?
   Thank you!